# Using PerformanceObserver API to get and save data for further usage with classes - JS

Tags: javascript, performance, class, monitoring

I want to get data provided by `PerformanceObserver` and use it in my app.

In my case, I want to get data from `PerformanceObserver` that responsible only for `css` files and do something (in this case just check if these resources are cached or not)

Here's the code example:

```
class Styles {
    static getStyleResources() {
        const styles = [];
        const po = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
            for (const entry of list.getEntries()) {
                if(entry.initiatorType === 'css') {
                    styles.push(entry);
                    return styles;
                }
            }
        });

        po.observe({ type: 'resource', buffered: true });
    }

    static isChached() {
        return Styles.getStyleResources().forEach(item => item.transferSize ?
            console.log("The data is cached") :
            console.log("The data is not cached") 
        )
    }
}
```

I also tried different approaches but nothing worked. What is the problem and am I going in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

PerformanceObserver works asynchrounously, so you can't directly extract the values of the styles array, since it is a continuous stream. I think you need to catch it, set a limit for styles length for example.

```
const po = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
            for (const entry of list.getEntries()) {
                if(entry.initiatorType === 'css') {
                    styles.push(entry);
                    return styles;
                if (styles.length === 3) {
                    console.log(styles) // returns an accessible array with 3 entries
                     }
                }
            }
        });
```